# WhatsApp chat list

Tags: android, whatsapp, mobile-application

I'm new to Android and making an app to analyze chats on WhatsApp. For this, I want my app to list the recent chats (personal as well as group) in the same order as in the WhatsApp app. Is this possible? If not please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please be specific with your problem, so that we can help. Your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I only want the list of my recent WhatsApp chats in a listview on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if this was possible. The contents of the chats are encrypted, and there is no real incentive that Facebook would have in letting you see that information. They would prefer that you stay in their app after all...

With that in mind, they do provide an api for starting a new chat presumably because this would drive more users to their app:

https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/

However, they won't let you escape when you are there.

Comment: No worries about the messages. I already found a way to get the messages. All I want is to list the chats in a listview in my app. So that when the user clicks one on the listview, the app generates reports.